# Custom slider with tkinter, double cursors on the same slider

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to create a "two cursors" slider in tkinter? I have my own simple design made with photoshop, I would need, if not looking, at least acting like this. I need to get two variables from the same list in a clean way.

my design

[image: 1]

Comment: an attempt of yours would be greatly appreciated, this seems like you would need to do this on `Canvas` and draw this stuff, there is no `tkinter` widget that does exactly this nor does any combinations of widgets to achieve precisely this come to mind, but this is nonetheless very possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [example]; this is to large a task for us to just write it for you and put in an answer.